# Как поднять локальный npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Поддерживает ли стандартный npm локальные репозитории? Как опубликовать компонент в свой локальный репозиторий, который не связан с глобальным?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry#can-i-run-my-own-private-registry

Comment: я это делал, затык вот на этом: 
npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
Какого юзера указывать?